# Can I use OpenID without server - locally?

Tags: javascript, openid, client-side

I want to write a JS app that will authenticate the users using openid. It will do all it's work and then pass effects to some parent webapp. The problem here is that I don't want to use any kind of server - just a local JS sending messages redirecting and stuff. I know it's weird but application I am writing is very specific and requires it. So questions are:
 - is it at all possible?
 - are there any ready solutions?
If it's not possible, can you tell me at what point it would fail according to you? I have read OpenID spec and I cannot find such a point.

Comment: "I know it's weird but application I am writing is very specific and requires it." Methinks you have an XY problem.

Comment: Quite possible, I am absolutely aware of that. Think about the possible causes I am not talking about X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should be perfectly possible.

- JS gets token from OpenID provider
- token is saved somewhere (e.g. cookie or HTML5 local storage)
- JS redirects to OpenID login
- JS handles callback

There's nothing here stopping you from doing it, except that it's somewhat unorthodox and offers absolutely no security, like any purely client-side login system.

Comment: Could you be more specific about security? I mean there are some potential threats that I am working to fix, but maybe I don't see something.

Comment: @niv Just think about it. If everything is implemented in Javascript which is running client-side, **I, the user, have full control over the script.** I can open my browser's debug screen and fiddle with your script all day long. I can comment out the entire login procedure if I want to. Since there's no trusted component involved that the user can't touch, there's no security. You might as well just ask the user for his email address and skip the entire OpenID procedure for all the security it gives you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! Thankfully, that's not a problem in my case. You can assume in this problem we cannot fiddle with JS. Any other security concerns you have? The way information is sent between me and OP, etc.?

Comment: @niv In that case it's as secure as any other client-side authentication. Meaning the user can eavesdrop on everything that's happening, which may or may not be a concern. Since the user is only logging himself in, there should be little concern about sensitive data being sniffed.